IoT GetThingShadow not getting billed
I have all my things billed into billing groups and the billing groups have tags.
Also, my things have thing types, and these thing types also have tags.
In Cost Explorer I'm able to split costs by these tags and for example, I'm able to know which resources are hitting different API Operations.
For example, I am able to see which resources cost me more in UpdateShadowOperations but my problem is that I'm not able to see GetThingShadow. This API Operation appears as untagged.
I don't have my lambdas tagged but I don't think it's necessary. Does anyone know what could be the problem?
Thank you
